# Powershell verb for destroying a resource

Tags: powershell, naming-conventions, powershell-2.0, code-standards

I've been trying to stick with [the approved list of Powershell verbs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714428%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) when naming my cmdlets. I have a function which creates a resource, so it's called New-ClearCaseView. I'd also like to make a function which destroys this resource once it is no longer in use. However, I don't see any pair verb to go with New. The Remove verb is closest I think, but that's for removing a resource from a collection, not for actually destroying a resource.

Any suggestions? Is there any more up to date list of accepted Powershell verbs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Remove* would be the normal verb to use (eg. `del` is an alias for `Remove-Item`).

*Unpublish* might be another possibility (but only if your *new* is being used in a sense like *publish*). Equally *Unregister* (normally paired with *register*).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Richard. The resource is really being created and destroyed, so register and publish aren't exactly appropriate. I think I'll go with Remove since it's the closest. The resource never actually goes into a collection, but since it has the "del" alias, it's close.

Comment: I agree.  Remove-Item is used to delete files, so Remove-ClearCaseView makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Anything wrong with 'delete' in your situation?

Comment: Delete is not a Powershell verb