# Cmdlet naming convention: verbs for destroying and/or removing from a resource

Tags: powershell, naming-conventions

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300783/powershell-verb-for-destroying-a-resource) question asks which verb to use to "delete" a resource created with `new-Thing`.  Remove is the natural accepted verb, and so you have a `remove-Thing` cmdlet.

But we have several cases where `Thing` is also a container, which we can add items to or remove items from. At the moment we have

```
    Remove-Thing myThing                   # Destroys myThing
    Remove-ItemFromThing myThing myItem    # Removes myItem from myThing
```

which is pretty horrible. Is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Comment: If `Thing` is a proper .NET object, I would probably implement `Remove-ItemFromThing` as a `Remove()` method in that class instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of ideas come to mind.

The first is that the objects in the container should not be named the same as the container. So if your container is Thing then you have:

```
Remove-Thing  #destroys Thing
```

The objects inside Thing should not be named Thing. Let's say that they are named Part. Then you would have:

```
Remove-Part Thing Part # Removes Part from Thing
```

This would remove a Part from a Thing container.

The other way that comes to mind would be to attach a method to Thing that removes a Part. So you would do:

```
Thing.RemovePart(Part)
```

Comment: We already have `Remove-Part myPart`, to destroy myPart. I can add an optional `-FromThing` parameter, which would look syntactically nice, but I'm worried this may be confusing/error prone.

Comment: @Rob If `-FromThing` would accept a value from pipeline, that would look very PowerShell-like to me: `$Thing | Remove-Part -Name myPart`.

Answer (score 1):

You could extend the members of your `Thing` container with a `Remove` method via `ScriptMethod`. So you could do this:

```powershell
$Thing.Item.Remove()
```

Given that there is no `Remove-Member` to pair with `Add-Memeber` cmdlet, this looks like valid approach.

Comment: I'm fairly new to PowerShell, I can't see where I'm specifying which item to remove. Do you mean `$Thing[$Item].Remove()`? Or `$Thing.Item.Remove($item)`?

Comment: Actually - looking for `Remove-Member` in PowerShell's intellisense showed me `Remove-RoleMember` from SqlAS, which suggests `Remove-ThingMember`.

Comment: You can do it both ways: `$Thing[Item].Remove()` and `$Thing.Item.Remove()` are equal. Off the top of head, only arrays require `$Array[Index]` notation, other object like `PsObjects`, `hashtables` and so on can be accessed either way.  You can also extend `$Thing` with `RemoveItem` method and pass Item name\id to it: `$Thing.RemoveItem(item)`.

Comment: @Rob `Remove-RoleMember` doesn't have a parent `Add-Role` cmdlet (I think the roles are fixed), so that makes sense for Analysis Services, but it doesn't feels right for me in your case.